# Network policy on Google kubernetes engine not being applied

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I was trying to use a network policy for a pod on my GKE cluster, but I saw it is not working, although I have network policy enabled both for master and nodes.

Then I tried deny-all network policy to see if it is my network policy that is wrong, or something with GKE, but to no avail.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

These are the Calico Pods that were installed on my cluster:

```
calico-node-vertical-autoscaler-c97d48744-h4fjj                1/1     Running   0          5m24s
calico-typha-59cb487c49-hf4sg                                  1/1     Running   0          5m20s
calico-typha-horizontal-autoscaler-55c949db8f-vtvrf            1/1     Running   0          5m24s
calico-typha-vertical-autoscaler-f7c48db59-lj9h6               1/1     Running   0          5m24s
```

calico-typha-horizontal-autoscaler log is full of this:

```
k8sclient.go:221] Falling back to extensions/v1beta1, error using apps/v1: deployments.apps "calico-typha" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:typha-cpha" cannot get resource "deployments/scale" in API group "apps" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

**Solution:**

After poking around and after Suren's comment about checking logs, I figured it might be the cluster is so small and it is not handling the load anymore, so changed my nodes pool to a bigger one, and now everything is fine, seems like GCP wasn't able to install everything for Calico, but no error or anything was showing.

Comment: can you recreate your pod after the network policy has been applied? Sometimes calico does not apply properly to pre existing resources.

Comment: I did, scaled down and back up all deployments. I tried deleting the pod for which I am doing the network policy. Nothing really helping.

Comment: I've had the same problems on GKE and, to be honest, I don't actually know what made it start working. I recreated pods (including calico pods), drained, deleted and recreated nodes. Sometimes it just seemed like enough time had to pass. The one thing I can say is your last netpol should work.

Comment: I also drained all nodes, upgraded k8s, tried everything too... Well my only solution now is to wait. Thanks for the input @PatrickW

Comment: it might be worth opening an issue tracker with google support. I don't think enough people used network policy for these types of bugs to really get reported and reproduced.

Comment: @PatrickW reading here: https://docs.projectcalico.org/v1.5/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/, I see there should be a pod calico-policy-controller in my kube-system namespace, but I don't have it. Do you think it is the problem, maybe calico didn't install correctly. Can you check if you have it?

Comment: I do, and it is necessary. It should have been created automatically when you endabled the addon and feature. You can try disabling network policy completely (master and node) and re-enabling it. Might have just been a transient issue while the addon was being enabled, if it happens again, though, submit an issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201735/discussion-between-codebird-and-patrick-w).

Comment: what are the logs from calico pods?

Comment: @suren which pod exactly? GCP was having issues yesterday, now again I just disabled / re-enabled network policy on my cluster to see if it will work, but still no calico-policy-controller pod and it is not working.

Comment: If you have no calico pods in `kube-system` namespace, then network policy is not enabled.

Comment: @suren check my updates.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. On the phone, and didn't see it.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue and your chat logs are not available. If you did resolve this, can you please add an answer to stackoverflow?

Comment: @LauriPiispanen yes I resolved it, and update the question to have a solution, calico wasn't installed correctly on my cluster because of not enough resources...